# How do i get the code to copmile every step of the elif operation?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
name = 'bot_name'

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def message_enter(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    get_to_know_me = types.KeyboardButton('About bot')
    get_to_know_currency = types.KeyboardButton('Currency')
    rate_you = types.KeyboardButton('Rate your photo')
    markup.row(get_to_know_me)
    markup.row(get_to_know_currency, rate_you)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Hi, {message.from_user.first_name}! What do you want me to do?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)

def on_click(message):
    if message.text == 'About bot':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         f'About-bot information')
    elif message.text == 'Currency':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        eur = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='EUR',
                                         url='')
        cny = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='CNY',
                                         url='')
        usd = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='USD',
                                         url='')
        markup.row(eur, cny)
        markup.row(usd)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'What currency do you want to check?',
                         reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == 'Rate your photo':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Send your picture')
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
        def get_photo(message):
            bot.send_message(message, 'Very good picture')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, on_click)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

So, everything works fine but one thing. When you choose the bot to rate your picture it sends you a message 'Send your picture'. And after that it should wait for the user to send a picture and respond with 'Very good picture' text, which it doesn't. It worked fine with callback_data structure, but doesn't work this way.